# How to select value "over" levels. Hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 11.

I like to copy ID value from LEVEL 50 as a LEVEL 92´s new ID value.
There is also LEVEL's 52 and 90 between 50 and 92
So I need to "jump over" these other two levels and fetch ID value from LEVEL 50.

I have tried several different ways to achieve this but no success.

Here´s one try but it didn't worked when reached LEVEL 92:

```
SELECT LEVEL, ID, PARENT_ID, ORGANIZATION,
       CASE WHEN LEVEL = 50 THEN DECODE(LEVEL,50,ID)
            WHEN LEVEL = 52 THEN DECODE(LEVEL,50,PARENT_ID)
            WHEN LEVEL = 90 THEN DECODE(LEVEL,50,PARENT_ID)
            WHEN LEVEL = 92 THEN DECODE(LEVEL,92,MIN(ID)
                   KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER PARENT_ID DESC))
       END AS NEW_VALUE
FROM A_TABLE;
```

Help is appreciated. Hope you catch idea and can give me some advices.

Huge Thanks.

Sample dataset and desired result:

```
LEVEL   ID    PARENT_ID  ORGANIZATION NEW_VALUE
50   07615461 09479551   07537724     07615461
90   07776685 07615461   07537724     07615461
90   08195786 07615461   07537724     07615461
92   09369810 09371824   07537724     09371824 should be 07615461
92   09369828 09371824   07537724     09371824 should be 07615461
92   09369836 09371824   07537724     09371824 should be 07615461
52   09371824 07615461   07537724     07615461
```

Currently my query return PARENT_ID for the LEVEL 92 ID´s, not ID from LEVEL 50 as I need.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Absolutely. I edited my original post with a sample. Hope it reveals better what is the issue.

Comment: Is `LEVEL` in the data or is it a result of your query?

Comment: LEVEL is in data. NEW_VALUE is what I looking for.

Comment: Looks like you need `connect_by_root`, but in this case you know that root is always `07615461`. Here is the syntax of [hierarchical query with your data](http://rextester.com/TTX9159), maybe this will help.

Comment: Great effort. I will check is there something I can use in my query. On the other hand, I actually don't know what is the root. These was just a sample ID´s from scenario where all LEVEL´s exists. 50 is the lowest one and 92 is highest and there is LEVEL´s 52 and 90 between them.

Comment: YES! Small modifications, bits and pieces from your code and I finally make it work. Huge thanks Ponder for your idea about connect_by_root.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fail to notice that in your query, only WHEN level = 92, you decode level 92. If you change it to the later code, I think you would receive desired results:

```
DECODE(LEVEL,50, ID)
```

After revision:

```
DECODE(LEVEL,92,MIN(ID)
                   KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER PARENT_ID DESC))
```

-- I think if you replace DESC with ASC (or remove DESC), it will work as requested. However, if you have lower ID value in the future, it will point to the lower value.

My final proposal:

```
SELECT LEVEL, ID, PARENT_ID, ORGANIZATION,
       CASE WHEN LEVEL = 50 THEN ID
            WHEN LEVEL = 52 THEN PARENT_ID
            WHEN LEVEL = 90 THEN PARENT_ID
            WHEN LEVEL = 92 THEN MIN(ID)
                   KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER PARENT_ID ASC)
       END AS NEW_VALUE
FROM A_TABLE;
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable but it return 'null' as a NEW_VALUE for all those ID´s in LEVEL 92.

Comment: OK, I made a mistake in reading the formula. Do you have lower level than 50? I edited my answer, so take a look at the second part.

Comment: LEVEL 50 is lowest one and almost every single time I need to point into ID which found in this level.

Comment: Did you try my second proposal i.e. to replace DESC with ASC?

Comment: Actually, I think that you don't even need decode - just add the value which is supported. Since you already check If level = 52, you don't need to use decode. Just replace the entire function with PARENT_ID, the same goes for 90, and 92 should have just MIN(ID)
                   KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER PARENT_ID ASC))